# How to AutoSize the height of a Label but not the width

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `Panel` that I'm creating programmatically; additionally I'm adding several components to it.

One of these components is a `Label` which will contain user-generated content.

I don't know how tall the label should be, but it does have a fixed width.

How can I set the height so that it displays all the text, without changing the width?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Just use the `AutoSize` property, set it back to `True`.

Set the `MaximumSize` property to, say, `(60, 0)` so it can't grow horizontally, only vertically.

Comment: If it seams not to work, check that 'borderStyle' is set to 'none'. Maybe you want to fix even MinimumSize (e.g. (60,13) for a single line widh fixed width (since MinimumSize.Width=MaximumSize.Width=60)).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Graphics.MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx):

```
public SizeF MeasureString(
    string text,
    Font font,
    int width
)
```

> The width parameter specifies the
>   maximum value of the width component
>   of the returned SizeF structure
>   (Width). If the width parameter is
>   less than the actual width of the
>   string, the returned Width component
>   is truncated to a value representing
>   the maximum number of characters that
>   will fit within the specified width.
>   To accommodate the entire string, the
>   returned Height component is adjusted
>   to a value that allows displaying the
>   string with character wrap.

In other words, this function can calculate the height of your string based on its width.

Comment: I think you should be able to use `Graphics.FromHwnd(myLabel.Handle)` to get the `Graphics` object.

Comment: Fwiw, if you do measurements like this then you should use TextRenderer.MeasureText().  Graphics.DrawString() is outmoded and doesn't produce the same output.  Technically, the UseCompatibleTextRendering property must be used to select between the two.  Painful.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a label and you want have control over the the vertical fit, you can do the following:

```
MyLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(MyLabel.Width, 0)
MyLabel.Height = MyLabel.PreferredHeight
MyLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(0, 0)
```

This is useful for example if you have a label in a container that can be resized. In that case, you can set the `Anchor` property so that the label is resized horizontally but not vertically, and in the resize event, you can fit the height using the method above.

To avoid the vertical fitting to be interpreted as a new resize event, you can use a boolean:

```
bool _inVerticalFit = false;
```

And in the resize event:

```
if (_inVerticalFit) return;
_inVerticalFit = true;
MyLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(MyLabel.Width, 0)
MyLabel.Height = MyLabel.PreferredHeight
MyLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(0, 0)
_inVerticalFit = false;
```