# Change .NET Label control's height to fit wrapped text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to make a custom error dialog. The dialog consists of three parts:

[image]

The human readable text is a `Label` with following settings:

- `AutoSize` - `false`
- `Dock` - `Fill`

I want to expand the label's height so that the whole text is visible in the window:

[image]

I tried many variations with docking and anchoring the text but nothing helped. Note that I don't want to expand width, only height!

I also tried this to no avail:

```
textBoxErrInfo.Height = textBoxErrInfo.PreferredHeight;
```

I also [found this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673638/607407) which suggests the following solution:

> Just use the `AutoSize` property, set it back to `True`.
>
> Set the `MaximumSize` property to, say, `(60, 0)` so it can't grow
>   horizontally, only vertically.

Obviously this doesn't work for a window that can be resized horizontally. And if this solution is employed, the label overflows out of the window instead of expanding it:

[image]

How to automatically expand the label vertically so that all the text is visible?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (so we can reproduce what you are seeing at our end).

Comment: @TomášZato I guess what you're saying is wpf

Comment: You can use TextRenderer.MeasureText Method to get the Size of the text that's in the label. Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ye7hc8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @eren That sounds promising, but I am astounded that microsoft does not have built-in feature for it. Every GUI framework I ever used could do this.

Comment: @TomášZato Well i don't know about such a feature, maybe someone else do :) Would like to provide you an example but don't have time for that atm. Anyway seeing your profile i'm sure you can handle it pretty easy by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Form, try setting AutoSize to True and AutoSizeMode to GrowAndShrink. (and make sure the Label is set to autosize too and  not set to dock.fill)